# Java static function on generics

Tags: java, generics, static

Hey I'm trying to write a function that calls a static function based upon its generic arguments.
I'm having the following code:

```
public class Model<T extends Listable>
{
    private Document doc;

    /*
        When the JavaBean is created, a Document object is made using
        the Listable parameter. The request string for the specific
        type is used to pull XML-data from the cloud.
    */
    public Model()
    {
        try
        {
            doc = cloud.request(T.getRequestString());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
    }

    /*
        getMatches (used in JSP as "foo.matches") generates a list
        of objects implementing the Listable interface.
    */
    public List<Listable> getMatches()
    {
        return T.generateMatches(doc);
    }
}
```

How do I do this, I'm just getting something about static contexts.
'non-static method `generateMatches(org.jdom.Document)` cannot be referenced from a static context'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned comment into answer:

You can introduce an instance variable of type T and call generateMatches on that. You cannot call generateMatches on the type T itself.

You could e.g. inject this instance variable via the constructor and store it in a private variable:

```
private T instanceOfT;

public Model(T instanceOfT){
    this.instanceOfT= instanceOfT;
}
```

In your getMatches method you can then do this:

```
return instanceOfT.generateMatches(doc);
```

Comment: Accepted the best, but unacceptable solution. - Changed to C++

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you do not have handle to any *object* of class `T`. Just saying `T.generateMatches(doc)` means you are making a static call to static method in class `T`. You need to have a *variable* of type `T` to call instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

What's the question ?

The reason is clear - the line "T.generateMatches(doc);" calls generateMatches through T, and T is type (class/interface), not instance.

Comment: Right, well how should I make my above code work, I guess thats the question

Comment: Introduce an instance variable of type T and call generateMatches on that, not on the type T.

Comment: @Eric you are the first person making sense on this page. Why not add this as an answer?

Comment: Either make both doc and getMatches() static (and set doc using some static method, of course) or go the way Eric suggested. Depends on your needs - Eric's solution looks better for you code.