# Invoking a static method from a generic

Tags: java, generics

I have an issue with a generic class in Java and I am not sure how to solve it. I started programming with java and generics a few days ago so it could be a very well known issue. My class definition is something like this:

```
public Class LocalAuthCommand<T extends LocalAuth> {
    public LocalAuthCommand() {
        ...
    }

    public String execute() throws CustomException {
          String result = super.execute();
          T obj = T.unMarshall(result);
    }
}
```

unMarshall is a static method that is implemented in all subclasses of LocalAuth. All T classes implement this method, but I don't know how to make Java know that unMarshall does exist as static method in T. Any ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Static methods don't require an instance.

Comment: Looks like it is better for the method to not be static.

Comment: What the code does is basically constructing a T object with some xml string (result). The code for unMarshalling the XML string is a static method in the T class. I need it to be static because I am building an object with the XML, so I dont have an instance yet I can use to call the method.

Comment: does LocalAuth define unMarshall method? or you define them only in subclasses? it should be in superclass so that compiler could know that T also has it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191459/java-static-function-on-generics?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LocalAuth, you can either have `public static String unMarshall(String result)` or `public abstract String unMarshall(String result)`. You cannot have a method that is both abstract and static.

Answer (score 0):

`T` is erased at run time, so the reference to `T` is substituted with the bounding class `LocalAuth` at the point of the call to `unMarshall`.  I can think of two ways around this:

1. Explicitly pass in the `Class` you want to `unMarshall` and make the call reflectively.
2. Make `execute` abstract and create a concrete subclass of `LocalAuthCommand` for each `T`, such that the exact `unMarshall` method you want to call for each subclass is known at compile time.

Comment: I think I will go with #2, it is the only way to implement this without having to use reflection. Thanks!